# Need to understand Javascript object references

Tags: javascript

I am looking at this piece of code from John Resig's website.  What I don't understand is when the ninja object is set to an empty object, the yell method is still available to samurai.

Is it because since there is still a reference lying around to ninja, it wasn't garbage collected?

```
var ninja = {
  yell: function(n){
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
  }
};


var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };

ninja = {};

console.log(samurai.yell(2)); //hiy
```

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#14 (Original source, I modified it a little to remove the named function expression).

Comment: `ninja.yell` isn't assigned by reference, it's copied.

Comment: Why is this passed by value rather than reference?  I thought all objects were passed by reference?

Comment: can you link to the original source? `yell(n-1)` doesn't reference any function in the snippet you've provided.

Comment: Nope, in reality javascript only passes by value

Comment: .. but for objects it's a copy of a value

Comment: @adeneo, that's not quite correct, `ninja.yell` and `samurai.yell` will share a reference to the same function object, the problem is that `ninja` is being overwritten with a new object completely.

Comment: @adeneo - i don't think you're right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: @learner that question answers this question perfectly.

Comment: "copy of a reference" is a good way to explain it, but the copy is still passed as a value, there are no true references, just copies.

Comment: Passing by reference means it's possible to pass a variable in such a way as to allow a function to modify the value of that variable in the calling context.
In other words, it creates an alias, a reference, to the variable in the calling context, and javascript has no such thing.
JavaScript just creates a local variable inside the function with the same reference value as the variable passed in, or a copy of the value passed in from the calling context so to speak, hence it really only has pass-by-value.

Comment: @zzzzBov no they don't; `ninja.yell` can be updated independently without affecting `samurai.yell`, because in the case of a method on an object, the method is copied.

Comment: @learner I just noticed that you are the OP _and_ you posted a link to IMO an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Mathletics, "`ninja.yell` can be updated independently without affecting `samurai.yell`" [nope, you're wrong about that one](http://jsfiddle.net/tnbs0z11/).

Comment: @zzzzBov point taken, but you're [wrong about which part i was wrong about](http://jsfiddle.net/tnbs0z11/1/). Updating `ninja.yell` to refer to a new function can be done without affecting `samurai.yell`; adding properties to `ninja.yell` DOES affect `samurai.yell` because it is the same object. The latter is the part I had wrong. Your fiddle demonstrates this, but the part of my comment that you quoted is, indeed, correct.

Comment: @learner this might help you understand too ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/1wk5eoe9/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following code:

```
var ninja = {
  yell: function(n){
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
  }
};
```

The value of *ninja.yell* is a reference to a function. The assignment:

```
var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
```

Assigns a value to *samurai.yell* that is a reference to the same function (i.e. the one referenced by *ninja.yell*). Then:

```
ninja = {};
```

Assigns a value to *ninja* that is a new, empty object. It has no effect on the value assigned to *samurai.yell*, which still references the function.

Variables have a value, values have a [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8). There is a special Type called the [*Reference Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) that is "*…used to explain the behaviour of such operators as delete, typeof, and the assignment operators*". So when an object is in an [*assignment expression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), the value assigned is Type Reference.

Hence the variable still has a value, but it's value is a reference.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `samurai.yell` refers to the _function assigned to `ninja.yell`_, not to `ninja.yell` itself. You can change the value of `ninja.yell` directly (not just blowing away the `ninja` object) without affecting `samurai.yell`

Comment: This sums it up nicely. I would only add that the only things that will be handled by the garbage collector are those things which are no longer referenced anywhere.

Comment: It's not a reference to the same function, it's a **copy** of the original function, which is why it's not deleted

Comment: In any case, this question is a duplicate of [Does JavaScript pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

Comment: @Mathletics—I think that's what "*Assigns a value to samurai.yell that is a reference to the same function*" says, but I'll add some words.

Comment: @adeneo—no, it's the same function. Functions are Objects, they are not copied in an assignment. You might say the value is copied, so it's a copy of the reference. It's not a copy of the object.

Comment: Okay, we're basically talking about the same thing, I call it a copy of a value as references doesn't really exists, but it's not a true copy, as in `ninja.yell != samurai.yell` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Break out the anonymous function which is referenced by 'yell' property of 'ninja':

```
function yell(n) {
  return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
}

var ninja = {
  yell: yell
};
```

Now it's a little easier to see that the function 'yell' does not get 'deleted' when you reassign 'ninja'.

When you do:

```
var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
```

You assign whatever ninja.yell references (which is `function yell()`} to 'samurai.yell'.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to look at the original unmodified source for this one:

```
 1. | var ninja = { 
 2. |   yell: function(n){ 
 3. |     return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
 4. |   } 
 5. | }; 
 6. | assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); 
 7. |  
 8. | var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
 9. | var ninja = null; 
10. |  
11. | try { 
12. |   samurai.yell(4); 
13. | } catch(e){ 
14. |   assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" ); 
15. | }
```

The change you made to change `ninja.yell` to `yell` is an invalid edit to the script.

> What I don't understand is when the ninja object is set to an empty object, the yell method is still available to samurai.

It's important to understand how assignment works in JavaScript. JavaScript has a lot of convenient shorthand notations that can make things harder to understand when you're new to the language.

```
var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
```

Is a shorthand way of saying:

```
var samurai;
samurai = new Object();
samurai.yell = ninja.yell;
```

When `samurai.yell = ninja.yell` is called, a reference to the `ninja.yell` function is added to `samurai`.

In JavaScript, functions are objects too. They are passed by reference. What `samurai.yell = ninja.yell` **does not do** is copy any sort of reference to `ninja`.

On line 9 of the example, **`var ninja = null` does not modify the function at `ninja.yell` in any way**. It also does not modify the object that was stored at `ninja` in any way. What it does is remove the reference to the object that was stored at `ninja`, and replace it with a value of `null`. This means that any other copy of the object referenced at `ninja` will still point to the object that was referenced at ninja.

It's easier to see with an example:

```
var foo,
    bar;

foo = {
    fizz: 'buzz'
};
bar = foo;
foo = null;
console.log(bar.fizz); //buzz
```

> Is it because since there is still a reference lying around to ninja, it wasn't garbage collected?

After line 9 of the example script executes, there are no longer *any* references to the object that had been at `ninja`. There *is* a reference to the function that had been at `ninja.yell`. What this means is that the `ninja` object can be garbage collected, but the `ninja.yell` object (which happens to be a function) cannot.

Comment: @RobG, the reference copied is of the function that happens to be at `ninja.yell`. No reference to ninja is copied, which is what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Dry-run the execution the way that a JavaScript interpreter would:

1. Create a new, anonymous, empty object (identified as `obj1`).
2. Create a new, anonymous, function called `func1` which does `return n > 0 ? ...`.
3. Add a new property to this object `obj1` called `yell` which is an alias for the function `func1`.
4. Assign a reference to this object to a new root property called `ninja` (variables can be thought of as field properties).

At this point, the "heap" looks like this:

```
func1 = n => return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"
obj1  = { yell: func1 }
ninja = obj1
```

5. Create a new, anonymous, empty object (identified as `obj2`).
6. Add a new property to this object `obj2` called `yell` which is an alias for the function `func1` - **not** an alias for `ninja.yell` - a reference to the "function value" itself is copied into `obj2.yell` rather than a reference-to-a-reference-to-a-function.
7. Assign `obj2` to `samurai`.
8. Create a new, anonymous, empty object (identified as `obj3`).
9. Assign a reference to this object to `ninja`.

At this point, the "heap" looks like this:

```
func1   = n => return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"
obj1    = { yell: func1 } // this no-longer has any references and will be GC'd at some point
obj2    = { yell: func1 }
obj3    = {}
samurai = obj2
ninja   = obj3
```

10. Call `samurai.yell` which will dereference `obj2` and then `func1` to successfully make the call.